# Google analytics for multiple tenant tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a multi tenant setup using the same HTML but different web urls
eg. tenant1.company.com , tenant2.company.com
since both use the same htmls the analytics code is same. How do i set up different codes for different tenants to get different data in GA

Answer (score 0):

Unless you intend to analytics between the two tenants you should be using a different web property id for each one.   There is really no reason to be storing the data in the same Google Analytics account.

Its just a simple matter of changing the javascript snippet on each site.